# What is tensor flows row reduction algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, open-source

I'm wondering what tensor flow uses to perform row reduction. Specifically when I call `tf.linalg.inv` what algorithm runs? Tensorflow is open source so I figured that it would be easy enough to find but I find myself a little lost in the code base. If I could just get a pointer to the implementation of the aforementioned function that would be great. If there is a name for the Gauss Jordan elimination implementation they used that would be even better.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

The op uses LU decomposition with partial pivoting to compute the inverses.
For more insighton tf.linalg.inv algorithm please refer to this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/inv

-

If you wish to experiment with something similar please refer to this stackoverflow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441509/how-to-implement-lu-decomposition-with-partial-pivoting-in-python)

Comment: But where's the source code?